# How did Aladdin trick Genie inside the cave with his first wish?

Tags: aladdin, aladdin-2019

In *Aladdin* (2019), by rewinding, Genie reminds Aladdin that he already used his first wish to get out of the cave but Aladdin argues that it didn't count as his wish.

How did Aladdin trick Genie inside the cave ?

Comment: Aladdin (the 1992 animated film) is one of my favorite movies and this is my biggest point of frustration with it. You asked about the 2019 version, but the concept is the same. Genie is supposedly bound by the laws of magic which place djinn at the command of their human masters. Djinn are presumably limited in many ways, otherwise they could use their magic to manipulate humans and, presumably, free themselves. If the Genie is able to cast wish-level spells (as opposed to what must have been visual tricks for his "friend like me" song) without being ordered to by a human, it breaks the rules

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**He didn't rub the lamp.**

> Distracted by his own lighter-than-desired shade of blue, the Genie didn’t notice as Aladdin deftly slipped the lamp out of his hands and into the outstretched hand of Abu. With the lamp safely out of his hands, he nodded. “Genie,” he said, “I wish you to get us out of this cave.”
>
> ...
>
> “I’ll do it,” Aladdin said, cutting him off. “I’ve got three, right?”
>
> “Two—” the Genie corrected. “You already used one.”
>
> Aladdin raised an eyebrow, a mischievous smile tugging at his lips. “Did I?” he said. “Or did you? Thought I had to rub the lamp.”
>
> <sub><sup>Aladdin - Official Novelisation.</sup></sub>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially the same trick as the animated film. Aladdin challenges Genie's pride, Genie gets them out of the cave voluntarily to prove that he can. Aladdin successfully argues that he never actually asks Genie to do so, so it's not a wish.

Comment: Not the same trick in the 2019 movie. The original trick was better.